# Best way to return search info from a database in php

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search, get

So I have a form for people to fill out, which is below... Once they fill that form out, how can I query it and return the information from my database?

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="agents.php"> 
<table>
                                <tr>
                                <td width = "20%">Last Name: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="LASTNAME" size="20"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td width = "20%">City: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="CITY" size="20"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>State: </td>
                                <td><select name="state" size="1">

    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AR">AR</option>
    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="CO">CO</option>
    <option value="CT">CT</option>
    <option value="DC">DC</option>
    <option value="DE">DE</option>
    <option value="FL">FL</option>
    <option value="GA">GA</option>
    <option value="HI">HI</option>
    <option value="IA">IA</option>
    <option value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="IL">IL</option>
    <option value="IN">IN</option>
    <option value="KS">KS</option>
    <option value="KY">KY</option>
    <option value="LA">LA</option>
    <option value="MA">MA</option>
    <option value="MD">MD</option>
    <option value="ME">ME</option>
    <option value="MI">MI</option>
    <option value="MN">MN</option>
    <option value="MO">MO</option>
    <option value="MS">MS</option>
    <option value="MT">MT</option>
    <option value="NC">NC</option>
    <option value="ND">ND</option>
    <option value="NE">NE</option>
    <option value="NH">NH</option>
    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
    <option value="NM">NM</option>
    <option value="NV">NV</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
    <option value="OH">OH</option>
    <option value="OK">OK</option>
    <option value="OR">OR</option>
    <option value="PA">PA</option>
    <option value="RI">RI</option>
    <option value="SC">SC</option>
    <option value="SD">SD</option>
    <option value="TN">TN</option>
    <option value="TX">TX</option>
    <option value="UT">UT</option>
    <option value="VA">VA</option>
    <option value="VT">VT</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="WI">WI</option>
    <option value="WV">WV</option>
    <option value="WY">WY</option>
</select><br><br></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>Zip: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="ZIP" size="30"/> </td>
                                </tr>

                                </table>

<br> <br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: @Christina : you might want to edit your post, to reformat your code, so it's easier to read, and use the formating options, so it's actually presented as code (There is a short syntax reference on the right of the edit form ; and a link to the full reference) ;; thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

As your form is in GET *(see the `method` parameter)*, and sends data to `agent.php` *(see the `action` attribute)*, `agent.php` will receive the data entered by the user, in the `$_GET` superglobal variable -- which is an array.

There will be one entry in that array for each field of the form ; and the key for each value will be the `name` attribute of the corresponding field.

Which means the `$_GET` array will contain something like this, for instance :

```
array
  'LASTNAME' => string 'my last name' (length=12)
  'CITY' => string 'my city' (length=7)
  'state' => string 'DE' (length=2)
  'ZIP' => string '12345' (length=5)
  'Submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

(I got this output using [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump), with Xdebug installed)

To store those data to a database, you'll have to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions, or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: there should be also a name for each option so get can return them also

Comment: @streetparade > I am not sure about that : without any "name" attribute on the "option" tags, I received the city I selected ;; And, judging from the HTML 4.01 specification, the "option" tag doesn't accept any "name" attribute : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

Comment: The appropriate place for the name attribute is in the Select tag as in the original question, not in the option tag.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is too large a question for a site like this. I suggest you check out some tutorials online about PHP and MySQL (or whatever your database is) for beginners. There are lots of good ones out there. Read two or three and when you get stuck with a specific problem, then post a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

You should really study PHP and MySql interaction for a while, at least the bases. Any answer given here (assuming someone understands the question) will only fix the single problem and move your "I'm stuck" point one step further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the tutorial here: 
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql
it will walk you through step by step how to do this.